# OOB functionality broken after August 2020 CU

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-on-prem, modern-experience, 2019, cumulative-update

After installing the August CU for SharePoint 2019 we have found that OOB functionality is now broken. We have 3 environments, DEV, UAT and PROD. DEV and UAT are both patched with the August CU and PROD is running the July CU.

Steps to reproduce: Create a new OOB Modern Communications or Modern Team site via CA. Load up the default home page and the following issues have been found:

**Site Settings > Site Information** generates a js error in

[image]

**Site Settings > Site Permissions** generates a js error in

[image]

**Site Settings > Change the look** link generates a js error

[image]

**Share site** link generates a js error:

[image]

These errors result in those respective menu actions not working. So we cannot share a site, view site information or permissions from the settings menu.

I am sure this is not a comprehensive list of all the issues, but it's what I've found so far. These issues are not present in our PROD environment which is on the July CU.

Any advice on this issue would be greatly appreciated.

All server in the farms have both CU and MUI Language patch installed.

Also, here are the js errors that are present in an empty oob communication site

[image]

Comment: Did you apply both KB 4484472 and KB 4484471?

Comment: Yes both the cu and mui language patch are installed

Comment: I've updated this post and included a screenshot of the oob empty site js errors, which are present without clicking anything. Pretty sure they have gotten worse after the aug cu/mui