# SharePoint 2019 On Premise OOB JS errors

Tags: sharepoint-server, modern-experience

Any insights into these JS errors would be much appreciated. These are present on a OOB Modern communications and team site. The seem to get progressively worse with each CU. Obviously they degrade the performance and the user experience. We are running SharePoint Server 2019 with the September CU (KB4484505) and Language Pack (KB4484504) both installed. We have 3 environments and the errors are present in all 3 environments. Super frustrating as it's all OOB, no customisation at all.

This is really something I need to get fixed, or at least understand if there is something wrong with my farm config that would cause these errors.I'd be interested in hearing from anyone else running SP2019 On Prem and seeing if you are getting similar issues.

[image]

Comment: Did you have similar issues when patching other previous CUs, not just for Sept CU? Did you have some solutions/features? You can check them at the farm level, site collection level, and site level. Also please create a new Modern Site, check if this issue occurs.

Comment: Only since the August CU this has been happening. The console errors in the post are from a new OOB Modern communications site. No customisations are activated on this site collection. The only customisations are a couple of apps deployed to the app acatalog, a web part solution and an app customizer, but they aren'tinstalled on this site.

I posted about the issue back in august but haven't been able to resolve the issue:
https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/284622/oob-functionality-broken-after-august-2020-cu?noredirect=1#comment302982_284622